# Error linking static boost_filesystem library with Qt Creator

Tags: qt, boost, mingw, qt-creator, qmake

I am getting an error when trying to link a static boost_filesystem library with QMake.

I know that my boost install is working, because I can link to it no problem outside of QMake like this:

```
g++ -o my_file my_file.cpp -IC:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0 -LC:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

I tried linking Qt with boost_filesystem like this at first, but it seems that it could not find the libraries:

```
LIBS += -LC:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
"-lboost_system not found -lboost_filesystem not found"
```

I read something about how you need to specify absolute paths to static libs when using QMake, so I've changes my LIBS line in my .pro to the following:

```
LIBS += "C:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_55.a" \
"C:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-1_55.a"
```

The libraries are found with this method, however I get the following error message:

```
     undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category()
```

I was under the impression that this error only happen when boost_system isn't linked! I seems like it is linked though, because it finds the proper library for it, and I know my install of boost is good because the same library links fine (with the same compiler) outside of Qt Creator.

Here's the include in mainwindow.h:

```
 include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

Here the full .pro:

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

TARGET = Downloader
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0
LIBS += "C:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_55.a" \
    "C:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-1_55.a"

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp\
    rar_process.cpp\

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h\
        rar_process.h\

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES += \
    graphics.qrc
```

And here's the full compiler output:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\mingw48_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\qt- downloader\Downloader.pro
C:/Qt/Qt5.1.1/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/cpp/build-Downloader- Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Release'
g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o release\Downloader.exe release/main.o  release/mainwindow.o release/rar_process.o release/qrc_graphics.o release/moc_mainwindow.o  release/moc_rar_process.o  -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmingw32 -lqtmain   C:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_55.a   C:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-1_55.a - LC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\mingw48_32\lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Network -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core 
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1a): undefined reference to  `boost::system::generic_category()'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x24): undefined reference to  `boost::system::generic_category()'
Makefile.Release:86: recipe for target 'release\Downloader.exe' failed
c:/qt/qt5.1.1/tools/mingw48_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../i686-    w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: release/main.o: bad reloc address 0x24 in section `.text.startup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release\Downloader.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/cpp/build-Downloader- Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Release'
makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently boost-system will not link against mingw gcc 4.8.0 if it was built with mingw gcc 4.8.1.

I re-built boost with mingw gcc 4.8.0 and linked against those libs, and now it works!

Comment: It means that there is binary incompatibility between the code generated by these 2 different versions of compilers. Since binary compatibility is preserved when the 3rd version number (patch) changes, the only reason why there could be binary incompatibility is most likely because one of the versions is SJLJ variant, and the other one is DWARF or SEH.

Answer (score 3):

GCC is very sensitive to the order in which you specify libraries during the linking stage. For example, if `libA.a` depends on `libB.a` and an executable `App` depends on both, then you'd have to invoke linker in the following way:

```
gcc main.o object1.o ... object2.o -lA -lB -o App
```

This implies that you have to change it to:

```
LIBS += "C:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-1_55.a" \
        "C:\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_55.a"
```

To be cross-platform, it's recommended to make your build more robust:

```
Boost_VERSION = 1_55
COMPILER      = mgw48

win32-g++* {
  LIBS           += $$(Boost_DIR)/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${Boost_VERSION}.a \
                    $$(Boost_DIR)/stage/lib/libboost_system-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${Boost_VERSION}.a
  PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$(Boost_DIR)/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${Boost_VERSION}.a \
                    $$(Boost_DIR)/stage/lib/libboost_system-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${Boost_VERSION}.a
}

linux-g++* {
  LIBS           += -L$$(Boost_DIR)/stage/lib -lboost_filesystem-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${Boost_VERSION} \
                                              -lboost_system-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${Boost_VERSION}
  PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$(Boost_DIR)/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${Boost_VERSION}.a \
                    $$(Boost_DIR)/stage/lib/libboost_system-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${Boost_VERSION}.a
}
```

**NOTE:** `Boost_DIR` would be treated as an environment variable here. So that you can flexibly build it on any system without hardcoding the system-dependent path to Boost. This is general practice in professional software development: try to hardcode as little as possible in your build system, whatever it is. Furthermore, it's reasonable to even make `Boost_VERSION` environment variable too. All you'd have to change then, are brackets to parentheses, i.e. `$${Boost_VERSION}` to `$$(Boost_VERSION)`.

Finally, notice that I've used forward slash `/` as a path separator for both Windows and Linux. Backward slash `\` is not only deprecated in QMake, but it is also discouraged in general. Once again, be cross-platform: simply let QMake handle the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and suggestsions. As insightful as they are, unfortunately changing the order of the linked libraries did not solve the problem and results in the exact same error message.

Comment: Well, in this case, something is wrong with your Boost libraries. Try running `nm libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_55.a | grep generic_category` and check if this symbol is even present there.

Comment: Haroogan,

That command returns a result. It's not a problem with the boost libraries, because remember, I can link boost-system and boost-filesystem no problem with the same compiler like this:

g++ myfile -Ipath/to/boost -Lpath/to/boost/libs -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem

Comment: To follow up on that thought, not only can I link no problem outside of QtCreator, but I can use boost::filesystem with no problems. For instance:

boost::filesystem::path p("some path");
std::cout<<boost::filesystem::space(p).free<<std::endl;

That will print the amount of free space on the drive. So the libraries are working. I am at a bit of a loss with this. Is there anything in QMake that I'm forgetting?

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting somewhere...
So apparently Qt is NOT using the same g++ compiler that boost works with when I use it outside of QtCreator. There is a Tools\bin folder in my Qt install that has g++ in it. I have verified that this is the version being used to compile the project. I am still confused as to why it is not working, though. The boost requirements state gcc 3.3. The g++ which links the libraries fine is gcc 4.8.1, and the Qt g++ is gcc 4.8.0.